# Change BaseFont size in ItextPdf

Tags: java, itext

I am using arial font using BaseFont in ItextPdf in my Java app. I am updating the acro fields of an editable pdf and regenerating. It's working all fine.

I am creating it as:

```
ArrayList<BaseFont> fonts = new ArrayList<BaseFont>();
BaseFont baseFont = BaseFont.createFont("/path/to/arial.ttf",BaseFont.IDENTITY_H,BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
fonts.add(baseFont);
```

and within my acroform I am attaching that font like this:

```
acroForm.setSubstitutionFonts(fonts);
```

How can I change the size of this `BaseFont`?

Comment: A `BaseFont` does not have a size.

Comment: @mkl so there is no way I reduce the size of baseFont?

Comment: You cannot reduce it because it doesn't have a size. As far as I know the font size used is the font size set in the default appearance of the field in question. Or if that size is 0, the largest size is used for which the field content still fits the field.

Comment: ok thanks @mkl I would reduce down the field's size (height) via pdf editor.